# Laravel Nova Metric card position

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Is it possible to move the card below the block with detail?

[image: explanation image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Laravel Nova doesn't allow this, you can use custom vanilla JavaScript to cut and paste it. It's a bit hacky but it works ‍♂️

This is all in the `Card.vue` that the `artisan nova:card yourname/customcard` command creates.

Give the card an `id` so we can find it later:

```html
 <card class="flex flex-col justify-center" id="custom-card">
```

Then find it again:

```js
let customCard = document.querySelector('#custom-card');
```

The listing of the details of that resource has a div with a custom `dusk` element and the value is set to `resourcename-detail-component`  where `resourcename` is e.g. `user`. You need to find that element and then append the card snippet to it:

```js
let anotherComponent = document.querySelector('div[dusk=resourcename-detail-component]');
anotherComponent.appendChild(customCard);
```

I've written this up here: [Laravel Nova: Move cards in Resource Detail View](https://repat.de/2021/08/laravel-nova-move-cards-in-resource-detail-view/)